# Asp.Net .Net 5 Lambda LINQ get the role name associated with the user account in Asp.Net identities

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-core, .net-5

I am using Asp.Net .Net5 with Entity framework 5

I have 3 tables

1. aspnetuser
2. aspnetroles
3. aspnetuserRoles  = link table

My current LINQ code returns back all data from users and userRoles, but none from the aspnetrole table. I want it to return back the user and the role they are currently assigned so that I can see if they are admin or standard.

```
    public async Task<IList<User>> GetAllEnabledAccounts()
    {
        var users = await _context.Users
            .Where(u => u.IsEnabled == true)
            .Include(r => r.UserRoles)
            .ToListAsync();
                    
        return users;
    }
```

aspnetuser table

```
id | username
--------------
1  | Jim
2  | Harry
```

aspnetRoles

```
id | name
----------
1  | admin
2  | standard
```

aspnetuserRoles

```
userId | roleId
----------------
   1   |   1
   2   |   2
```

When querying it should return back the user Jim showing that he is admin and Harry showing that he is a standard account. How do I type up the LINQ query to output the information correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your code, I suppose the aspnetuser and aspnetRoles was configured [many-to-many relationship](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key), right? If that is the case, you could refer to the following sample, and using the **InClude**, **ThenInClude** and **SelectMany** method to query the related entities.

Sample code as below (The Authors and Books table contains many to many relationship, BookAuthor is the join table, similar with the aspnetuserRoles table):

```
        var result = _dbcontext.Authors
            .Include(c => c.BookAuthor)
            .ThenInclude(c => c.Book)
            .SelectMany(c => c.BookAuthor.Select(d => new BookAuthorViewModel()
            {
                Id = d.Author.Id,
                AuthorName = d.Author.AuthorName,
                BookName = d.Book.BookName,
                ISBN = d.Book.ISBN
            })).ToList();
```

The Models as below：

```
    public class Book
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string BookName { get; set; }
        public string ISBN { get; set; }

        public IList<BookAuthor> BookAuthor { get; set; }

    }

    public class Author
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string AuthorName { get; set; }

        public IList<BookAuthor> BookAuthor { get; set; }

    } 

    public class BookAuthor
    {
        public int BookId { get; set; }
        public Book Book { get; set; }

        public int AuthorId { get; set; }
        public Author Author { get; set; }
    }
```

Create a ViewModel to display the query result.

```
    public class BookAuthorViewModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string BookName { get; set; }
        public string AuthorName { get; set; }
        public string ISBN { get; set; }
    }
```

Then, the output like this:

[image]